# GLFW setting callback functions

Tags: c++, types, callback, glfw

What `data type` to use when setting a callback functions in `GLFW`?

I try setting a function  to type `void` but gives me a `compile error`. Changing it to `void __stdcall` gives me an `RT error`, but how do I use the `typedef`'s of `GLFW` such as `GLFW*fun`? I think this is the right one to do. I really need an example source code.

btw, I define GLFW as **`GLFW_DLL`**

**UPDATE**

My code's look like this:

(I did it in three ways)

**1**

prototype. because `these*` are below `main`
this one gives me a compile error(invalid conversion)

```
void MouseClick(int, int);
void Keyboard(int, int);
//...
```

**2**

```
//appending `__stdcall` get compiled but gives me `RT error`

void __stdcall MouseClick(int, int);
void __stdcall Keyboard(int, int);
```

**3**

on my other project, I use `GLFW_BUILD_DLL` and compiles in `MSVS` with casting.
`glfwSetKeyCallback((GLFWkeyfun)Keyboard);`
but now, I can't do it in `MinGW` with the `GLFW_DLL`

```
void MouseClick(int x, int y) {

}
```

in `main`...

```
int main() {

//glfw intialization...

glfwSetKeyCallback(Keyboard);
//other setters

}
```

but, how do I do it this way?

```
GLFWmouseposfun MousePos {

}

//...
```

Comment: It would help if you could show us some code. Both a callback and how you try to set it would be good.

Comment: And of course it would also help if you could provide the _exact_ error message, and not edit it. And also point out in the shown source where the errors are.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg please look again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.glfw.org/GLFWReference27.pdf) for GLFW v2.x the prototype for what you pass to `glfwSetKeyCallback` (etc.) is

```
void GLFWCALL functionname( int key, int action );
```

Here is a complete C program which will print out the key events:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

void GLFWCALL keyfun(int key, int action) {
  printf("%d %d\n", key, action);
}

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwOpenWindow(640, 480, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(keyfun);
    while(1) {
      glfwSwapBuffers();
    }
}
```

If this code doesn't work you are likely linking to GLFW incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Ahm, sorry my fault. I just didn't noticed that I have this `Vec2f To_OGL_Coords(int x, int y)` inside `void MousePos(int x, int y)` which I haven't included in my post.
As I said, it is Vec2f which I left out the 3rd(z) coordinate to `NULL` that causes the runtime error. `Method number 2` should work here, same as Jacob Parker's answer. I just really don't know much the effects of those pointers if not used correctly.

(PS. I am working on 2D that's why I neglected the z-coordinate. My bad)